# Different One-To-Many relationships with same entities in Django

Tags: django, django-models

How would one go about implementing two different One-To-Many Relationships between the same entities in Django?

For example:
Suppose we have two relationships between a physical movement and muscles involved. For each movement I want to be able to distinguish between its main acting muscles and its supporting muscles. In practice I would introduce two tables (movement2primarymuscle, movement2supportingmucsle) and create a row with foreign keys for each relationship in each table.
What's the Django way of implementing this with Django models?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done like this:

```
class Movement(models.Model):
    primary_muscle = models.ForeignKey(Muscle)
    supporting_muscle = models.ForeignKey(Muscle)
```

If you are thinking about many-to-many relationship (the described db model seems to be many to many) then like this:

```
class Movement(models.Model):
    primary_muscles = models.ManyToManyField(Muscle, related_name="movement_primary")
    supporting_muscles = models.ManyToManyField(Muscle, related_name="movement_supporting")
```